# Call a command-line-argument from inside a method?

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments

I am having an issue calling a command-line argument from inside a method.

This is a snippet from my script. In the first few operations, where the argument is passed as a method option/parameter, the argument value is correctly mapped. In the last operation, where the argument is called inside the method, the argument is passed as text. Is there a specific syntax I am missing to call the variable from inside a method?

```
# sets the command-line argument as a global variable
evidence_name = ARGV[0]

# The argument value (evidence_name)is successfully called below as an
# option/parameter
evidence = processor.newEvidenceContainer(evidence_name)
evidence.custom_metadata = { 'Barcode' => evidence_name }
evidence.addFile(evidence_path)
evidence.save

# Instead of calling the argument value (evidence_name), the method is
# reading evidence_name as text. So the script is searching for
# "evidence_name" and not the value that I specified from the command-line
# at runtime.
all_files = current_case.search('evidence-metadata:evidence_name AND contains-text:1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are missing string interpolation.

```
"evidence-metadata:#{evidence_name} AND contains-text:1"
```

Comment: Thanks sawa. I tried that but it seems the method still reads the #{evidence_name} as a string: Caused by: InvalidQuery.message: Query syntax is invalid: evidence-metadata:#{evidence_name} AND contains-text:1
 at com.nuix.storage.search.queryparser.c.parse(SourceFile:115)
 at com.nuix.storage.search.queryparser.b.a(SourceFile:110)
 at com.nuix.storage.stores.search.z.a(SourceFile:143)
 ... 9 more

Comment: I don't think you followed what I wrote here. If you cannot type as what I wrote here, then copy it, paste it, and try it again.

Comment: I copy/pasted what you wrote and it worked. :) When I tried, I had single quotes instead of the double quotes. Many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: That is what I thought.